# Android Concept: Does Datasource belong in Activity or Fragment

Tags: android, json, web-services, android-fragments, android-activity

**Question**: Assuming I have a web service which returns a JSON which I deserialize into a (list of) POJO(s), should each Fragment get a copy of the datasource or should I keep the datasource only in the activity and let the fragment(s) get the data via a callback interface (which I set in onAttach())? Or is there even another, better way?

**WHY**

I work with Android for quiet a while now but I think I still have not fully understood some very basic principles and I hope you can help me clarify things. In one of my applications, I use `Volley` to call a web service which returns JSON formatted data.

I use `GSON` to deserialize the JSON into POJOs. I then use greenrobots `EventBus` to send the new data around so I can update the UI. Currently all my fragments are registered as subscribers and each fragment stores a reference to the data.

I think I am doing this wrong because what if a fragment is currently not being displayed (they unregister from EventBus in onStop()). They could miss an update of the model and when a Backstack is popped, they could display an outdated model, right?

So what would be the best way to store the model so that all my UI components and controllers always display the latest version of the model? I'm fearing that one or the other component (Fragment and/or Activity) might miss an update and then displays outdated data.

What is Androids way to store models retrieved from web services and make them accessible for activities and fragments?

I think my main problem is that I can refresh the data in multiple activities and fragments. For example I could reload the data after a pull-to-refresh of a list of entries but renaming an entry would also cause an update - but only of this particular entry.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using sqlite to store the data and then displaying it? 
What I would do is as follows:

- Fetch data from service as a json
- Parse the json and store it in a sqlite table
- Read from the sqlite table as and when required

The advantage in doing so is that you are able to store new data as well as update the old one and as you said you can use pull down to refresh functionality, this proves helpful to store the latest data as well as the old one and always display the latest data as you are fetching from a datasource that is being updated.

Comment: I was thinking about using some sort of persistence like SQLite or Realm but on the other side that might be just a little bit over the top since I most likely deal with only a bunch of JSON objects and I will have to reload them every time the app starts or was inactive for a short while. Updates come in pretty regular between every 5 seconds to once an hour (gps position updates of remote devices). I also was thinking of using a Firebase realtime database but currently the serverside backend only offers me JSON based REST web services.

Comment: Maybe a Singleton could do the job of being a datastore and keep those POJOs in memory but I wonder if Android actually has some best practice for that.